# retrieve original version of package function even if over-assigned

Tags: r

Suppose I replace a function of a package, for example `knitr:::sub_ext`.
(Note: I'm particularly interested where it is an *internal* function, i.e. only accessible by `:::` as opposed to `::`, but the same answer may work for both).

```
library(knitr)
my.sub_ext <- function (x, ext) {
    return("I'm in your package stealing your functions D:")
}
# replace knitr:::sub_ext with my.sub_ext
knitr <- asNamespace('knitr')
unlockBinding('sub_ext', knitr)
assign('sub_ext', my.sub_ext, knitr)
lockBinding('sub_ext', knitr)
```

**Question: is there any way to retrieve the *original* `knitr:::sub_ext` after I've done this? Preferably without reloading the package?**

---

(I know some people want to know why I would want to do this so here it is. Not required reading for the question). I've been patching some functions in packages like so (not actually the `sub_ext` function...):

```
original.sub_ext <- knitr:::sub_ext
new.sub_ext <- function (x, ext) {
    # some extra code that does something first, e.g.
    x <- do.something.with(x)
    # now call the original knitr:::sub_ext
    original.sub_ext(x, ext)
}
# now set knitr:::sub_ext to new.sub_ext like before.
```

I agree this is not in general a good idea (in most cases these are quick fixes until changes make their way into CRAN, or they are "feature requests" that would never be approved because they are somewhat case-specific).

The problem with the above is if I accidentally execute it twice (e.g. it's at the top of a script that I run twice without restarting R in between), on the second time `original.sub_ext` is actually the previous `new.sub_ext` as opposed to the *real* `knitr:::sub_ext`, so I get infinite recursion.

Since `sub_ext` is an *internal* function (I wouldn't call it directly, but functions from knitr like `knit` all call it internally), I can't hope to modify all the functions that call `sub_ext` to call `new.sub_ext` manually, hence the approach of replacing the definition in the package namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `assign('sub_ext', my.sub_ext, knitr)`, you are irrevocably overwriting the value previously associated with `sub_ext` with the value of `my.sub_ext`. If you first  stash the original value, though, it's not hard to reset it when you're done:

```
library(knitr)
knitr <- asNamespace("knitr")

## Store the original value of sub_ext
.sub_ext <- get("sub_ext", envir = knitr)

## Overwrite it with your own function
my.sub_ext <- function (x, ext) "I'm in your package stealing your functions D:"
assignInNamespace('sub_ext', my.sub_ext, knitr)
knitr:::sub_ext("eg.csv", "pdf")
# [1] "I'm in your package stealing your functions D:"

## Reset when you're done
assignInNamespace('sub_ext', .sub_ext, knitr)
knitr:::sub_ext("eg.csv", "pdf")
# [1] "eg.pdf"
```

**Alternatively**, as long as you are just adding lines of code to what's already there, you could add that code using `trace()`. What's nice about `trace()` is that, when you are done, you can use `untrace()` to revert the function's body to its original form:

```
trace(what = "mean.default", 
      tracer = quote({
          a <- 1
          b <- 2
          x <- x*(a+b)
      }), 
      at = 1)
mean(1:2)
# Tracing mean.default(1:2) step 1 
# [1] 4.5
untrace("mean.default")
# Untracing function "mean.default" in package "base"
mean(1:2)
# [1] 1.5
```

Note that if the function you are tracing is in a namespace, you'll want to use `trace()`'s `where` argument, passing it the name of some other (exported) function that shares the to-be-traced function's namespace. So, to trace an unexported function in **knitr**'s namespace, you could set `where=knit`

Comment: AHh, I suspected as much (irrevocably overwriting the value). I had hoped one could do something like reload `knitr` in a private/"fresh" environment and grab the value from there. However, I am perfectly happy to reset the value when I'm done (why didn't I think of that?!) and the case that inspired the question is indeed a case of addin lines of code to the existing function, so I can even use the `trace` method (nice btw! never really used `trace` before).

Comment: @mathematical.coffee -- I guess you could always do something like this, using a system call to retrieve the function's definition from a fresh R session: `x <- system2("Rscript", c("-e", shQuote('dput(knitr:::sub_ext)')), stdout=TRUE); xx <- source(textConnection(x))$value; environment(xx) <- asNamespace("knitr"); assignInNamespace("sub_ext", xx, asNamespace("knitr"))` . But that starts to seem fairly ridiculous, doesn't it?!

Comment: @isomorphismes You bet! I especially like `trace(..., edit=TRUE)`, which turns out to be very useful for trying out ideas during development. (Its only shortcoming there is that it won't let you edit the formal argument list, but any changes to the function body are fair game.) Cheers.